# Map of unique pointers, .at() with a raw pointer

Tags: c++, dictionary, pointers, std, unique-ptr

Say I have a map:

```
std::map<std::unique_ptr<SomeType>, SomeOtherType> map;
```

Obviously, this doesn't work because the key value of our map is a unique ptr and not a raw one:

```
//a pointer from somewhere else in the code
SomeType* p = ...;
auto result {map.at(p)};
```

What one could do instead is something like this using std::unique_ptr.get():

```
SomeType* p = ...;
for(auto& entry : map) {
    if(entry.first.get() == p) {
        //do whatever
    }
}
```

It's a very ugly and probably inefficient way of going about it, however. My question is simply whether there is a way to use the .at() function somehow in this case.

Comment: Using pointers (smart or not) as keys are rarely needed, and often wrong. If you have two pointers that point to two different object instances, but the object instances are otherwise "equal", they will still be different as keys (because it's the pointer that is the key, not the object they point to).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude here there are two pointers that point to the *same* object

Comment: Why do you think that you need the key to be `std::unique_ptr<SomeType>` rather than just `SomeType`?

Comment: I'm using such a map in a networked program I'm creating. The map store a TCP socket object as its key and another object containing other information (such as the IP address) as its mapped value. Now that you mention it, I actually don't see a reason for SomeType to be a unique pointer. I suppose I did it like that because the mapped value does indeed have to be a unique pointer for other reasons. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: While still thinking the @Caleth's solution is the best, you can define your struct with unique_ptr and someother class and use a map of <string,customstruct> (or int or whatever)

Comment: If your socket object doesn't have any virtual functions, you don't need to wrap it in a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: I've run into a bit of a tricky dilemma after trying some things. Basically, the function that the socket calls to receive a packet is not const qualified, and so I cannot call it while iterating over my map since map keys are immutable. It does work with pointers however, so I'm thinking I'll keep them as ptrs and use @Caleth's solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C++ 14, you can provide a transparent comparator

```
template<typename T>
struct PtrCompare
{
    std::less<T*> less;
    using is_transparent = void;
    bool operator()(T* lhs, const std::unique_ptr<T> & rhs) const { return less(lhs, rhs.get()); }
    bool operator()(const std::unique_ptr<T> & lhs, T* rhs) const { return less(lhs.get(), rhs); }
    bool operator()(const std::unique_ptr<T> & lhs, const std::unique_ptr<T> & rhs) const { return less(lhs.get(), rhs.get()); }
}

std::map<std::unique_ptr<SomeType>, SomeOtherType, PtrCompare<SomeType>> map;
```

That doesn't help with `at`, but does allow you to `find` based on anything that you can compare

```
SomeType* p = ...;
if (auto it = map.find(p))
{
    // use it->second
}
else
{
    throw std::out_of_range;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! As a quick note, to make this compile in GCC 8+, const should be added to the call operators (https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-8/porting_to.html)